# Where UnityContainerElement in Unity 2?

Tags: unity-container, unity2.0

I was in Unity 1.2, use the following code:

```
UnityConfigurationSection UnitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Unity");
Dictionary<string, IUnityContainer> Containers = new Dictionary<string, IUnityContainer>();

foreach (UnityContainerElement element in UnitySection.Containers)
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    Containers.Add(element.Name, container);
    element.Configure(Containers[element.Name]);
}
```

but, I couldn't do so in the Unity 2.0 beta2,
because The class 'UnityContainerElement' does not exist in Unity 2 beta2.

How can I do this in the new version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It have been renamed to ContainerElement.